# Webpack interprets aliases as path strings

Tags: webpack

I've created an alias:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'Images': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/images'),
    },
  }
```

When im trying to use it:

```
background-image: url("Images/test.jpg");
```

im getting an error:

```
Error: Can't resolve './Images/test.jpg'
```

As i got from error, webpack just passes my aliased string as plain path. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html and css add `~` before alias.

```
background-image: url("~Images/test.jpg");
```